# How many blessings for Rashi and Rabeinu Tam tefillin?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilin, rashi, rabbeinu-tam

How many brachot are said when donning two pairs of tefillin (Rashi and Rabeinu Tam)?  Does it matter how much time has passed between the two donnings (the one before Shacharit and the second after Shmona Esre)?

(I do not refer to taking off a pair of tefillin to use a bathroom and then donning them again. I am asking about wearing two different pairs of tefillin, sequentially or simultaneously, that are donned in order to fulfill the mitzva of tefillin following both Rashi and Rabeinu Tam interpretations of the mitzva.)

Comment: The question boils down to "are these Tefillin actually Kosher or just fulfilling some side opinion which we don't really rule like". Generally people assume Rabbenu Tam Tefillin are in the latter category, but for any other Machloket you'd have to ask that question from scratch. If the Tefillin are kosher, you'd say a blessing when donning them. If they basically aren't, you wouldn't. There are plenty of Machlokot about Tefillin that you could try to be strict for if you wanted to

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second pair is Rabeinu Tam the accepted minhag is NO BROCHO. The question of time would only be with your "regular " tefilin and say in the middle of Shachris you had to do carpool... and now you are back to finish davening.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Ruby. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. MY is putting significant emphasis on sources since we don't really know you.Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch (O.C. [34:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.34.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) brings down the halacha:

1. Preferably, he should wear both the Rashi and the Rabbeinu Tam tefillin simultaneously (as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFKCwVKf034&t=497s)).
2. Next best thing: he should don the Rashi tefillin with a bracha, immediately take them off, and put on the Rabbeinu Tam tefillin, so that the bracha extends to both pairs.
3. If he is unable to do the above, he should don the Rashi tefillin with a bracha (as normal), wear them until after Kriyas Shema and Tefillah, take them off, and don the Rabbeinu Tam tefillin without a bracha.

Clearly you wouldn't recite a bracha on the Rabbeinu Tam tefillin in your case.

A bracha is never recited on Rabbeinu Tam tefillin directly, since technically the halacha follows Rashi in this regard (ibid. [34:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.34.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Comment: 34:1 just says the popular custom is like Rashi, not that "A bracha is never recited on Rabbeinu Tam tefillin directly, since technically the halacha follows Rashi" It doesn't mention brakhot or halakha at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair enough. Although "Minhag Ha'Olam" is a little more authoritive than just a minhag.

Comment: Maybe? Do you have any other usages of the term to compare to?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe Shabbos candles would fall under that category, but I'm honestly not sure.